# text on image kineticJS

Tags: kineticjs

i have a problem, if it is possible to put text on the image.

this is easy example how it should be, but text does not appear.

```
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var x =  0;
  var y = 0;
  var width = 500;
  var height = 500;
  var imageObj = new Image();

  imageObj.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(imageObj, x, y, width, height);
  };
  imageObj.src = 'http://blaaah';

  context.fillStyle = 'white';

  context.fillText('Hello World!', 150, 100);
```

Comment: it is easily done, it's just that your image is loading after the text is written. You have image.onload and that waits for the image to load, in the meantime you are drawing the text

Answer (score 1):

See my comment above, change your code to this:

Same as bighostkim says, its just the order that needs to change.

```
 var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
 var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
 var x =  0;
 var y = 0;
 var width = 500;
 var height = 500;
 var imageObj = new Image();

 imageObj.onload = function() {
      context.drawImage(imageObj, x, y, width, height);

      context.fillStyle = 'white';

        context.fillText('Hello World!', 150, 100);
 };
 imageObj.src = 'http://blaaah';
```

Comment: also, you marked this as kineticJS, but your code is just vanilla javascript, maybe you should use kineticJS constructors for your text and image, then you can change the z-index on them and redraw

Comment: thanks for advices they are very helpful for me. And I have one question. Is it possible to change text with input? As you typed I want to use conscructors and stage.. So I rewrite this code to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14696875/change-width-stage-from-input  I am a beginner with Kinetics and your advices are awesome, thaks.)

Comment: This link is to change width but its the same problem.)

Comment: yes, it is possible to change text with inputs. If you use the constructors in kineticjs you can do mytext.setText('My Text Here'); assuming that mytext = new Kinetic.Text();

Comment: so I rly do not know what i am doing wrong.. I did it as you typed, but it does nothing .

Comment: I'll put it on codepen beacause of adding jquery and kinetic at the same time.. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/sgzlx I want to change the text and if you would be so kind, look at that width when you click on the thumbnails..  Thanks a lot... I am doing it for my website and if you will help me, I will and your reference, as you want..

Comment: I fixed the text changing. I don't understand what you want to do with the width. What width do you want to change?

Comment: ur great..thanks for that text.. So width and height.. If you click on the Thumbnails, canvas will change image(background). But If you notice and click on the third thumbnail, that  image on canvas is not correct.

It should take width and height and put there right measurements, but it cant take from thumbnails because they are very small and it could take original width and height from image source(it is ,,src" of that thumbnail)

I hope you understand that problem and I do not know how to fix it 
Thanks

Comment: so click on thumbnails should change width and height of image and canvas at last

Comment: if you do yoda.setHeight(500); this will change the height of the image to 500. If you do stage.setHeight(800); this will change the height of the stage. if you want each picture to be the size you defined in the html you can use Jquery: $('#pictureWrapperCreator img').width() //returns width.

Comment: I think I answered all your questions, the programming, trial-and-error are up to you.

Comment: yeah, so I solved it, and now width and height show correct. But There is one bigger problem, how is possible if you click on thumbnails (change images on canvas more times) it will start lag computer, Its really unpleasant behaviour and I think It is connected with no redrawing text after clicking on Thumbnails. So last thing is repair $('#pictureWrapperCreator img').click.. function and everything will be fine. If you have time, please fix it, or I will accept all advices

Really thanks for time to help me

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ydxIH

Comment: sorry, create a new question on the forum. Your original question was already answered.

Comment: sure.. this is that topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14725432/changing-image-causes-big-lag

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your image is drawn after your text is written on canvas.
Here is the sequence.

1. you define image with callback onload
2. You write 'Hello World'
3. image is loaded and you draw image on canvas

As you see, your image is overwriting the text, that's why you don't see it.

Here is the working  example[http://jsfiddle.net/7DU4e/][1]