# change width stage from input

Tags: kineticjs

Could someone help me?

I have a stage and image and i want to change width and height from input.
this is code and it does no work :/ help me.)

var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'containerCreator',
    width: imageWidth,
    height: imageHeight
    });

```
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.onload = function(){
  var yoda = new Kinetic.Image({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    image: imageObj,
    width: imageWidth,
    height: imageHeight
  });



  layer.add(yoda);
  layer.add(vrchnyText);
  stage.add(layer);  

  };
  imageObj.src = imageSource;

  $('#vrchCreator').keyup(function(){

    stage.width = $(this).val();        
    stage.height= $(this).val();    
    layer.add(yoda);
    stage.add(layer);
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You want to change this to:

```
$('#vrchCreator').keyup(function()
{ 
   stage.setWidth(parseInt($(this).val()));
   stage.setHeight(parseInt($(this).val()));
   layer.add(yoda);
   stage.add(layer);  

});
```