# Changing image causes big lag

Tags: kineticjs

I have a problem that after clicking on thumbnail(mini picture that causes change background on canvas),page will start lag and if you more and more click to other thumbnails,     lags are very big and other effect is that text does not appear after change image(this is connected with these lags I think again) Could someone tell me where is problem or just look at my code and try to repair it?

thanks so my because I really do not know where is problem:(

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ydxIH

Answer (score 0):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bsdHp

the main error here was that you were doing:

```
    layer.add(yoda);
    layer.add(vrchnyText);
    layer.add(spodnyText);
    stage.add(layer);
```

on every click of a picture.

This slowed down everything because you were not 'changing' the picture and text, you were 'adding' it each time. So what you want to do is to change the the picture and text, not add it each time, then just draw the layer again.

```
    vrchnyText.setText($(this).val().toUpperCase());
    layer.draw();
```

Also, you do not need to change the width and height of the stage and picture each time, since it is always 500, this REALLY slows it down.

Comment: layer.draw() reallly helped.  Then I did, that I removed object and thant  created again, but it solved layer.draw() And sorry for spending your time but the last thing is that after clicking on thumbnails, image redraw without lags but text dissapear, I think its because of yoda is redrawing a text..I tried yoda.draw();spodnytext.draw() but still does not work.

Comment: This is the last thing to understand kinetic and  redrawing because everything is clear for me Thanks

Comment: click the image again, so click it twice, this is an image caching issue similar to the unload function, the drawing is in a different order than you might expect.

Comment: yes, I see. so double click can ,,fix" it, thanks... 

I know I am asking too much but really, nobody can help me with this, and this is only one way how to learn it. So I am asking another question. If u are so kind  look at it, thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14734833/todataurl-does-not-work-in-kinetic-js